# Can the dns' domain be in its own spf record?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, dns-zone

I'm finally fixing up my dns zone files in Gandi, which has a handy feature that lets me use the same zone file for several domains. So I can keep 1 zone file for a single domain and all its tld's.

But normally, when you set up the SPF record for eg `domain.com`, you don't actually add "mx:domain.com", because it's implied.

Will this thrown an error if you do?

Here's an example SPF record for domain.com.

The "correct" one:

```
v=spf1 mx mx:domain.info mx:domain.net mx:domain.org ~all
```

And here's the one I would like:

```
v=spf1 mx mx:domain.info mx:domain.net mx:domain.org mx:domain.com ~all
```

Is that allowed, or not?

Comment: You should consider switching "~all" to "-all". That tilde lets everyone know you don't really know what you're configuring and some servers (like the ones I run) will hold it against you when raking your e-mail for spam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not implied.  There's nothing implicitly assumed about what systems you want to authorize.

You're ***explicitly*** setting `mx:domain.com` by setting `mx` at the start of the record - they're functionally identical when the SPF entry is on `domain.com`.

That said, you should not run into any validation errors simply because you specify the same thing twice.

Comment: +1 But note that only 255 characters can be in a single SPF record... So if you own example.com for every TLD you'll run into problems. But that's somewhat unusual.